# Slow react forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, performance, render

Do you have any experiences with fast react form? I have tried redux-form, antd form. Both are slow. When I am writing inside input fields.

The form what I want to do is quite complicated. It is a dynamic form with many fields. See attached image, that type is select where the selected value is displaying next fields.

Here is example in antd. https://codesandbox.io/s/yjz6r2z2l9

[image: React form]

Answer (score 0):

Your form is working slow because of rerendering entire form content on every state change, even single keystroke. React needs some optimizations to avoid that - f.e. `shouldComponentUpdate` and `PureComponent` usage.

Try [formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/arrays). Beside `<Field/>` it has `<FieldArray/>` and `<FastField/>`, probably usabeful for this case.

Remove `console.log`, use react dev tools.

Comment: I was not successful with shouldComponentUpdate. But I handled it by separating form into multiple forms. Then it is rendering just that 'sub-form'